# MockMVC keeps throwing HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code in a test:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/bk/getBk?sd=1262296800000&nOD=3"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
                .andExpect((jsonPath("$.", Matchers.hasSize(3))))
                .andDo(print());
```

I cannot understand why it keeps throwing `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException` because it finds the handler and the path seems ok.

Here is what I have from `print()`

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = GET
         Request URI = /bk/getBk
          Parameters = {sd=[1262296800000], nOD=[3]}
             Headers = {}

             Handler:
                Type = com.ihbs.booking.BkController
              Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.ihbs.bk.BkDTO>> com.ihbs.booking.BkController.getBk(com.ihbs.bk.GetBkForm,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws com.ihbs.exception.InvalidEmailException,com.ihbs.exception.IDSmallerThanZeroException

               Async:
       Async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException

        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 400
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

I don't know how to get the stacktrace.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Now show us everything else, the test, the config, the handler method, etc. Provide an MCVE.